# Can not access Chromecast receiver debug page by http://chromecastIP:9222?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

In my whitelist process, I submit the requests and didn't get response email, so submit a fews days later again.

Then one day received 3 response emails with 3 different URLs.

However, I still can't see the receiver debug page [http://192.168.1.101:9222](this is my chromecast local IP), where did I miss?

The device lists are empty in my sender app too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Search here on StackOverflow and you'll see a lot of similar threads

Comment: Thank you. I reset my device then check the checkbox of "allow updates..."in configuration page. a few hours later, the debug port 9222 is okay and I can get access it now. Thanks again.