# Why is whitelisted Chromecast IP for development blocked with err_connection_refused?

Tags: chromecast

I already read this ([Can not access Chromecast receiver debug page by http://chromecastIP:9222?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425388/can-not-access-chromecast-receiver-debug-page-by-http-chromecastip9222)) and similar threads. I am not sure if they are outdated from the pre-release SDK but at any rate here is my tale of woe...

Chrome is giving me these details when attempting to browse my Chromecast IP:

Google Chrome's connection attempt to 192.168.2.78 was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

*NOTE* - I did remember to add the :9222 suffix

My Chromecast device appears to be whitelisted.
From the cast.google.com/publish/#/overview console page it lists both my Application ID and my Serial #.

The App ID is fine if that even matters as I have successfully run many github sample apps using it.

The serial # I entered is correct as I was meticulous reading it with a magnifying glass off the device (felt like Sherlock Holmes).

The status for my Serial # lists, "Ready for testing"

I did this all after a factory reset today.

I then unplugged the USB cable from the Chromecast dongle and counted to 30 and reseated it.

This is exactly what the instructions on the cast developer site instructed.

I have seen some posts where people say it could take hours but that seems to be pre-release posts where there were alot of issues.

So basically I ready every stackoverflow post on this, followed all instructions, everything looks good and works right (I can cast no problem) even with my own code for both Android & Web but I just cannot browse, http://:9222

I just get err_connection_refused

I can ping it without the :9222 suffix as well.

Since it says, "Ready for testing" I assume I do not have to wait for Google to process this.

Finally I was triple sure to check, "Send Serial # to Google for updates" in installation app.

Can anyone provide guidance please?

Thanks!!

These are the instructions I followed (meticulously I might add)
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration

To register your Google Cast device:

Sign in to the Google Cast SDK Developer Console.

From either the Overview page or Devices page, click Add New Device.

Enter the serial number of your device. ( I TRIPLE CHECKED THIS)

The serial number on a Chromecast is a 12-digit alphanumeric string, laser-etched (not printed) on the back of the device and begins with a 3, 4 or 5. It may be easier to read if you take a picture of the serial number then enlarge it. The serial number is also printed on the package.
Enter a description, and click OK.

This is just a friendly name for your device (it does not need to match the name you gave to the device during user setup).

Wait fifteen minutes before continuing. (I waited till it says, "Ready for testing")

Once registration is complete, the Status for the device will read "Ready for Testing."

In the Chromecast setup app, select your Chromecast and check the box, Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates.

Restart your Chromecast by disconnecting the USB cable from the device, then reconnecting it.
After restarting the device, check whether you can access http://:9222 from a chrome browser on the same WiFi network.

** AFTER ALL THIS STILL GET ERR CONNECTION REFUSED **

Once you can access the URL, your device is ready for development. If you can't access the URL, check the serial number you entered in step 3, above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) (search for Debugging). The Registration page will be updated later today or tomorrow to remove item number 8 at the bottom of the page. In short, you need to have your own application running on the Chromecast device to be able to attach your chrome debugger to it. Also see this [post](https://plus.google.com/117916055521642810655/posts/THNdcXCwRUb).

Comment: Thanks Ali. I was coming back to this page to answer my own question as I figured this out using the github. The IP came and went and then I realized it was because I was running the particular github sample, "ChromecastReceiver". - Thanks for all your answers the past 48 hours. Most helpful!